# Sum of independent discrete and continuous random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I was going through [Distribution function of the sum of poisson and uniform random variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618188/distribution-function-of-the-sum-of-poisson-and-uniform-random-variable?rq=1) and my sir stated that below distribution function is continuous. \begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X+Y \le a) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\lfloor a\rfloor-1} \mathbb P(X = i) + \mathbb P(X = \lfloor a\rfloor, Y \le a-\lfloor a\rfloor)
\end{align*}

Here X is continuous and Y is discrete. How can we conclude that the distribution function is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a random variable (or its distribution) is continuous if its probability of any single value
is always $0$.

If $X$ is discrete (with countable set of possible values $S$) and $Y$ is continuous, then for any $z$,
$$ \mathbb P(X+Y=z) = \sum_{s \in S} \mathbb P(X=s,\; Y= z-s) = 0 $$
because $\mathbb P(X = s,\; Y = z - s) \le \mathbb P(Y = z-s) = 0$.
Therefore $X+Y$ is continuous.  Independence is **not** needed.